# A word for a wild, uneducated, random guess that turns out to be correct

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Sometimes I find an outsider in a conversation with little or no knowledge about the subject or ground already covered in the conversation makes a random guess about a question no one can answer and it turns out to be correct. I have experienced this often enough that it seems like there might be a word or phrase for it, but if there is I don't remember it. Any insight would be appreciated!

Example:

> Wow, Bert only said that it might be catalytic converter because he heard us say that term earlier in the conversation. He doesn't know anything about cars. I can't believe he was actually right! That was a real ________!

Comment: "Lucky guess." I don't think there's a single word for it.

Comment: [*fluke*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fluke)

Comment: 'FLUKE' suggested by Rahul is a very good option for this case.

Comment: @Rahul - Please make it an answer.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214935/what-is-it-called-when-something-you-previously-took-to-be-a-mistake-turned-out

Comment: On Car Talk, they call it "unencumbered by the thought process."

Comment: "Even a blind chicken finds a kernel of corn now and then" but I can't back it up with any references that aren't to a music album or what seems to me to be low grade references. Blind squirrels and nuts are supposedly used in the American South in a similar way.

Answer (score 8):

> [**fluke**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fluke)
>
> NOUN
>
> An unlikely chance occurrence, especially a surprising piece of luck.
> *‘their victory was a bit of a fluke’*

Answer (score 3):

*Wild guess* is a perfectly fine phrase, but if you don't like that one, I'd suggest *a shot in the dark*:

> ***[A shot (or stab) in the dark](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a_shot_(or_stab)_in_the_dark)***
>
> PHRASE
>
> An act whose outcome cannot be foreseen; a guess.
>      *‘their experiments were little more than shots in the dark’*

Comment: This doesn't capture the "turns out to be correct" part, which is critical to the question being asked.

Comment: @JohnY, maybe a _lucky_ shot/stab in the dark in this case then.

Answer (score 3):

You might say,

> He really **caught lightning in a bottle** that time!

The idiom [**catch lightning in a bottle**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lightning_in_a_bottle) refers to succeeding at an extremely difficult task—usually through a single stroke of great luck or through a remarkable series of individually minor instances of good luck.

The expression alludes to the Benjamin Franklin kite experiment, but it seems to have first became idiomatic in U.S. baseball, in reference to a team or player that, against all expectations, plays at a very high level. The downside of the expression is the implication that the player or team is likely to revert to the mean (that is, to mediocrity) when the stroke or run of good luck ends.

Comment: I disagree.  This is the precise opposite of a fluke.

Answer (score 3):

"Lucky [guess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guessing)."

> An apparently unreasoned guess that turns out to be correct may be
>   called a happy guess, or a **lucky guess**, and it has been argued
>   that "a 'lucky guess' is a paradigm case of a belief that does not
>   count as knowledge".

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 2):

**Beginner's luck** is an appropriate idiom here -- colloquially, it refers to the success a novice may have, even though it is clearly not due to skill or knowledge.

A more strict/scientific discussion of beginner's luck is here, and I'd say it's used the most colloquially referring to things like games, but I can't imagine that your meaning wouldn't be taken as it's common in casual conversation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beginner%27s_luck

Answer (score 1):

It's just dumb luck! This refers to the  "wild, uneducated, random" part of your question.

> **dumb luck** 1. pure chance.

[Definition of *dumb luck*](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=dumb+luck&oq=dumb+luck&aqs=chrome..69i57.3731j0j4&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

**Dumb luck** is when a **long shot** *hits the bull's eye!*

> ***long shot*** (noun) an attempt or guess that has only the slightest chance of succeeding or being accurate.

[Definition of *long shot*](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=long+shot&oq=long+shot&aqs=chrome..69i57.2756j0j4&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#xxri=20)

> **hit the bull's-eye** [Also, *hit the mark* or *hit the nail on the head*] Be absolutely right

[Definition of *hit the bull's eye*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+the+bull%27s-eye)

Comment: If you click on the tiny question mark on the editor toolbox, and then *advanced help* it explains how to embed links.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A thanks for the tip and for pointing out the 2 answers -- there is some asynchronicity with my browser but I have deleted the incomplete answer which was posted by error

Comment: bravo! you did it,

Comment: @Mari-Lou A it took a bit of figuring out because I have no experience with that sort of thing,  but seeing those nice embedded links, it's **so** worth it!

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that was just [fortuitous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fortuitous).

> fortuitous -lucky; fortunate:

Or
It was [more by luck than judgement](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/more-by-luck-than-judgment?a=british).

> more by luck than judgment- by chance and not because of any special skill:

or
It could have been [providential](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/providential)

> providential - opportune, fortunate, or lucky.

Answer (score -1):

While not usually used for guessing, the phrase "Hail Mary" would be understood. In football, a Hail Mary pass is one made at extreme range with no obvious guarantee that it will be caught. The image is of the quarterback making a desperate prayer before throwing the ball.

Comment: Perhaps the prayer is not desperate, the situation is.